# Stop a number at a certain range

Tags: java, math, rotation

Basic problem but I can't seem to wrap my head around it:

I have something that rotates and I want to stop it at a certain range.

So I want it to return false if the rotation (which is in double) is within a certain range.

Example

Rotation = 182, StopAt 180, Accuracy 2. So should stop.

Rotation = 182, StopAt 180, Accuracy 1. So should not stop.

Current I have:

```
/**
 *
 * @return
 * number = 100, current = 105, accuracy = 10
 * Example
 * 105c / 100n = 1.05..
 * 10c / 100n = 0.1..
 */
public boolean stopAtRange(double number, double current, double accuracy)
{
    if(current / number) + accuracy)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `if(current / number) + accuracy)`?

Comment: `if` expects `boolean` value, not `double`. Something like `if (a+b>0)` is correct but `if(a+b)` is not.

Comment: The code you posted cannot be even compiled.
Is accuracy range in percentage or absolute?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your examples, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java `if` only takes boolean values, and integer values aren't converted to boolean.

To achieve what you want, your method should be like this

```
public boolean stopAtRange(double number, double current, double accuracy)
{
    if( Math.abs(current - number) <= accuracy)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This work both if `current` is bigger or smaller than `number`. If you only want to stop if `current` is bigger or at least equals to `number`, than you should remove the `Math.abs`

I also suggest to use this version:

```
public static boolean stopAtRange(double number, double current, double accuracy) {
  return Math.abs(current - number) <= accuracy;
}
```

because it's more compact, and is optimized, for performances as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following will stop if `current` is +/-`accuracy` away from `number`:

```
public boolean stopAtRange(double number, double current, double accuracy)
{
    if( Math.abs(current - number) <= accuracy)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I'll try my best to help. :)

This code won't compile:

```
if(current / number) + accuracy)
```

Firstly, you've opened one bracket and then closed two. You would want:

```
if((current / number) + accuracy)
```

Secondly, this won't evaluate to a Boolean value (true or false), which is necessary for your if statement to work. You want:

```
public boolean stopAtRange(double number, double current, double accuracy)
{
    if(Math.abs(current - number) <= accuracy) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This works out the difference between your numbers (100 & 105) and confirms if they are within the range (10).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if accepts a boolean value, not a double. Something like:

```
public boolean stopAtRange(double number, double current, double accuracy)
{
    if(Math.abs(current-number) <= accuracy)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```